# shell script looses access after calling maven

Tags: shell, maven

Here's what I am trying to do with my windows batch file script

```
cd C:\git\foo
call mvn clean install
cp target\foo-bar.war C:\jboss\standalone\deployments\foo-bar.war
call C:\jboss\bin\standalone.bat
```

After the call to mvn, the execution stops. How do I make the other two lines execute as well?

Note: I have gow installed and I use bash commands such as cp, rm, cd etc...

It works when I uninstall gow. But then I have to change all my commands to windows shell commands. Is there any chance to make it work with gow installed?

Comment: @Kent: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/call.mspx

Comment: @DanielBarbarian oh.. microsoft...  I need update my understanding of shellscript..

Comment: @Kent No need, I think you will be doing fine nevertheless :-)